# Finding out zero frequency values from a column with inner join

Tags: sql

I have two tables named courses and teachers. I need to find the list of teachers who don't take any courses.

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE TABLES' IMAGE]

This is the query I wrote for getting the teacher who took the most numbered courses -

```
SELECT t.name AS teacher_name
     , COUNT(c.teacher_id) AS courses_taken 
  FROM courses c
  JOIN teachers t
    ON c.teacher_id = t.id 
 GROUP 
    BY c.teacher_id 
 ORDER 
    BY courses_taken DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE QUERY RESULT]

By reversing this query I am getting the teacher's list who take minimum numbers of courses which is 1 but I need to find the list of teacher who don't take any courses.

Comment: Can't do your requirement with an inner join.. Use a right join (because teachers is currently your right hand table, but personally i would flip it round so teachers is on the left and use a left join) and a WHERE that demands the courses side is NULL

Comment: (ps; you won't need a group by either; each teacher who teaches no courses will be represented only once in the output)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please do not post images which only contain TEXT. (Post the TEXT, and not the image)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @luuk I'll never understand why people go to all the extra effort of loading a screenshot in compared to Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V needed to put text in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left Join and Where condition can help you.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM teachers t 
  LEFT 
  JOIN  courses c 
    ON t.id = c.teacher_id 
 WHERE c.teacher_id IS  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Teachers don't usually "take" courses.  They "teach" courses.  Students "take" courses.

That said, `not exists` seems appropriate:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM teachers t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM courses c
                  WHERE c.teacher_id = t.id 
                 );
```

If you think about this, it is almost a direct translation of your question:  Get teachers where there is no course that the teacher teachers.